# Time to archive - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, archive, partitioning

I am researching archiving options for our database application (highly normalized schema) and would appreciate expert feedback.  We are using Sql Server 2005, but if something works only in 2008 R2 that may be an option for us.

Primary reason for archiving is to remove old data on an annual basis.  The criteria to determine which objects can be archived will not be straightforward (ie: not just filtering by a date, but many more considerations involved).

Archiving needs to be basically a push button on the application (ie: not by actual DBA on the database server).

Data should be retrievable, but perhaps by special request.  Perhaps an object and all its related pieces could be searched for and brought back into the current database?  (Again, via the application interface.)

Another important requirement is to maintain integrity of related data.  If an archived object is related to a non-archived object, I want to ensure the non-archived object can't be deleted through the interface.  Currently we have many checks in place to ensure you can't delete items if they're in use, and I hesitate to alter all of those checks to join an _archive table or use a new view.  Is there another way?

I have read about table/index partitioning and although it is interesting, it sounds like perhaps a LOT of work considering how many stored procedures, views, indexes, etc that we use.

Comment: Partitioning wouldn't work for you since you criteria are complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is your motivation for archiving?**

You mention you want to "remove old data" but since you need it to be constantly available that doesn't make any sense.

The easiest thing to do in your situation will be a "soft" archive, where you add an `Archived` bit field to all your tables that indicates if a row is active or not.  Then all your existing referential checks stay in place, but you need to add a filter on that bit in your views or queries, and add it to most of your indexes.

You don't really need to do an offload since you can't move the data off the server anyways.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I realize I didn't mention speed as a reason for the archive, but can you tell me if there would be any speed benefit (assuming indexes reflect the bit) and if the benefit would be equal or close to actually removing the data to a different table?

Comment: The benefit would be close to the same as offloading to the other table.  You also won't have the overhead of inserting/deleting all those rows since the data itself won't be moving, and you won't have the fragmentation to deal with.